# ImportError:cannot import name symbol_database

Tags: protocol-buffers, caffe

I'm new to caffe.When I try the caffe,the problem occurs.Anyone can help?Thanks in advance!

```
>>> import google.protobuf
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/llzxo/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/llzxo/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>
    import caffe.io
  File "/home/llzxo/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 8, in <module>
    from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
  File "/home/llzxo/caffe/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
ImportError: cannot import name symbol_database
```

Comment: This has the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843481/python-project-using-protocol-buffers-deployment-issues

Answer (score 4):

It may be due to version incompatibility of your installed protobuf. Try to upgrade protobuf by:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade protobuf
```